# How do I mount a guest Windows share on host Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, network-shares

In Ubuntu 12.04, I have a VirtualBox virtual machine running Windows Server 2008.

I have a directory set up to mount `/media/windows`, which is `chmod 777`.

When I mount the share from the Windows server under Ubuntu, the profile of `/media/windows` changes, and I no longer have write permissions.

Here is my mount command

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=Administrator,password='password',rw //WIN/SHARE /media/windows
```

Comment: It looks like a missing comma between the `password` and `rw` options.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.
I added my Linux user id to the mount statement and it handed ownership of the mounted directory to me...

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=Administrator,password='password',uid=1,rw //WIN/SHARE /media/windows
```

Comment: You should mark your answer as "correct" then, even if it's your own :)